# Summarise numeric column by group dplyr r

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, sum

I have a data set DATA with column REF_AREA, TIME_PERIOD, ROW_ID, X
I want to sum by REF_AREA and TIME_PERIOD
When I do this

```
 DATA %>%
 group_by(REF_AREA,TIME_PERIOD) %>%
 summarise(X_ = sum(X))
```

I got his as a result, so not by REF_AREA TIME_PERIOD

```
     X_
1 72147423
```

I looked on the stackoverflow and tried many ways found here, but not the result expected yet.

Comment: Please give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: Maybe that is because `plyr` is loaded after `dplyr`. See difference in `mtcars %>%  group_by(cyl) %>% dplyr::summarise(mpg = sum(mpg))` and `mtcars %>%  group_by(cyl) %>%  plyr::summarise(mpg = sum(mpg))`

Comment: Comment from Ronak solved it